# Facebook secure canvas url bypass

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, facebook-canvas

I want to make my app public, but I don't have validate SSL cert and hosting with unique IP for it. I read that the changes ommiting https:// will come in October. How can I change my app to working by http until October's changes?

Generally problem for now is: when i enter to facebook via https and go to app, there is a error about untrust cert and apps isn't loaded.

If there is no way to avoid "migration" changes, can any1 tell me is there any chance to run MySQL database on Heroku?

Comment: if i remember it right new apps are forced to https , only old apps have a chance to work until October

Comment: That was October 2011 - your app would technically  be breaking facebook's policies by being a canvas app without HTTPS. Also, users using Facebook over HTTPS cannot access your app

Comment: _“can any1 tell me is there any chance to run MySQL database on Heroku?”_ – https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/built-on-mysql